# Loop over list in Angular and print intermediate heading, reusing structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object looking something like:

```
people = {
rightHanded :[
    {"name":bob,
     "age": 23
    },
    {"name":dave,
     "age": 20
    }
],
leftHanded :[
    {"name":sarah,
     "age": 23
    },
    {"name":lisa,
     "age": 20
    }
]};
```

I want to reuse the same structure for both kinds of people

```
<tr><td>Right handed</td><tr>
<tr ng-repeat="person in people.rightHanded">
    <td>person.name</td>
    <td>person.age</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Left handed</td><tr>
<!-- Don't want to repeat the same structure -->
<tr ng-repeat="person in people.leftHanded">
    <td>person.name</td>
    <td>person.age</td>
</tr>
```

I want the structure like:

```
Right handed
bob            23
dave           20
Left handed
sarah          23
lisa           20
```

I could put the value inside the persontag, but can I then only write the line "left handed" once?

Comment: Yes, like you can use filter in that case. and put tag of right-handed or left-handed manually.

Comment: @RishiPrakash, not sure I understand how. If you know could you provide it as an answer?

Comment: @yes working on it, wait :)

Answer (score 3):

json - tweaked to work well with ng-repeat:

```
people = [
  { 
    title: "Right handed",
    list: [
      {"name": "bob", "age": 23 },
      {"name": "dave", "age": 20 }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Left handed",
    list: [
      { "name": "sarah", "age": 23 }, 
      { "name": "lisa", "age": 20 }
    ]
  }
];
```

template:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="x in people">
  <td>{{x.title}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="p in x.list" ng-repeat-end>
  <td>{{p.name}}</td>
  <td>{{p.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

see [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zfgrE3W6GQVIBfDRujMd?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create custom filter which will flatten the array.

**Markup**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people | customFilter: 'rightHanded'">
    <td ng-bind="person.name"></td>
    <td ng-bind="person.age"></td>
  </tr>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('customFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(values, side) {
    var returnValue = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function(val, index) {
      angular.forEach(val, function(v, i) {
        v['side'] = index; //here you inserting side
        returnValue.push(v)
      });
    });
    return $filter('filter')(returnValue, {side: side}, true);
  }
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqczsFFcgzQW7iKnc9tQ?p=preview)

Comment: how is this custom filter is working, can u elaborate a little?

Comment: OP wants separate list, if you understand.

Comment: @all is correct, but see OP need to show Lefty and Righty in separate list with a tag , you are showing all of them in one go. He don't want to merge the result in one list but the JSON of Left handy and right handy in to one.

Comment: @RishiPrakash Now it is configurable through filter

Comment: I can write `people.rightHanded` instead of `people | customFilter:'rightHanded'`. Looks like you just created a filter to access a property of an object, cool, but... why? ;)